# Java: String format prints doubles with coma

Tags: java, scala, format, decimal, decimalformat

Working on a scala project, I can't figure out what's happening.

I have the following scala code:

```
val getUrl = (lat: Double, lon: Double, zoomLevel: Int) =>
  s"reverse.php?format=json&lat=%2f&lon=%2f&zoom=${zoomLevel}"
    .format(lat, lon)
```

`formatLocal` is regular Java code.

On my compute, it prints something like `reverse.php?format=json&lat=44.1234&lon=5.6788&zoom=10`.

However, on one of our customer's computer (I can't run debug on it), it formats doubles with coma, like `reverse.php?format=json&lat=44,1234&lon=5,6788&zoom=10`.

I also tried

```
.formatLocal(Locale.ENGLISH, lat, lon)
```

With no success. However the following works as expected:

```
  val DECIMAL_FORMATTER = new DecimalFormat("#.######")
  s"reverse.php?format=json&lat=${DECIMAL_FORMATTER.format(lat)}&lon=${DECIMAL_FORMATTER
  .format(lon)}&zoom=${zoomLevel}"
```

But I have to define the number of decimals, and I'd prefer the String.format approach.

Do you have any explanation of the behavior?

Comment: Are you trying to format the string in Java or Scala? In Java, you can just pass `Locale.US` and it will always format doubles with a comma. For example `String.format(Locale.US, "%f", d);`.

Comment: On my Mac, `String.format(Locale.US, "%f", 0.55);` results in `res1: String = 0.550000` - there is no coma

Comment: If you pass `Locale.US` to the `format` method, it will use `.` on every computer. If you don't pass a locale then it will use the value of `Locale.getDefault()`, which depends on the default locale of each computer.